# Project onto vector that is not starting at the origin

Tags: linear-algebra, projection

In the image below we can project vector $d$ onto $c$ using formula
 $$proj_c(d) = c \frac{c•d}{d•d}$$ But what if I need to project onto a vector that is not at the origin? How do I project vector $d$ onto vector $b$?

[image]

Comment: @Jim Thank you! So would this be correct $$proj_b(d) = (b-a) \frac{(b-a)•d}{d•d} + a$$?